# Malloc and pointer

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to understand one code which I found on YouTube. I know how malloc works but I don't understand how this code works. He points to the first element in the heap and allocate space for another entities?

```
#define u8 uint8_t 
#define u16 uint16_t 
#define STACK_SIZE 32
#define HEAP_SIZE STACK_SIZE * 4
#define HEADER 4

static u16 IN_USE;

typedef struct virtual_memory
{
    u8 stack[STACK_SIZE];
    char** unmapped;
    u8 heap[HEAP_SIZE];

    struct
    {
        char** data;
        char** bss;
        char* text;
    }data_t;
}virtual_memory_t;


typedef struct entity
{
    u8* ptr;
    int size;
}entity_t;


entity_t LIST[40];


entity_t* new_entity(size_t size)
{
    if (LIST[0].ptr == NULL && LIST[0].size == 0)
    {
        static virtual_memory_t vm;
        LIST[0].ptr = vm.heap;
        LIST[0].size = HEAP_SIZE;
        IN_USE++;
    }

    entity_t* best = LIST;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < IN_USE; i++)
    {
        if (LIST[i].size >= size && LIST[i].size < best->size)
        {
            best = &LIST[i];
        }
    }

    return best;
}

void* w_malloc(size_t size)
{
    assert(size <= HEAP_SIZE);

    size += HEADER;

    entity_t* e = new_entity(size);

    u8* start = e->ptr;
    u8* user_ptr = start + HEADER;

    *start = size;

    e->ptr += size;
    e->size -= size;

    assert(e->size >= 0);

    return user_ptr;
}


void w_free(void* ptr)
{
    u8* start = (u8*)ptr - HEADER;

    LIST[IN_USE].ptr = &(*start);
    LIST[IN_USE].size = (u8) * ((u8*)ptr - HEADER);
    IN_USE++;
}
```

Question:

```
LIST[IN_USE].ptr = &(*start);
LIST[IN_USE].size = (u8) * ((u8*)ptr - HEADER);
```

Why this piece of code the same like this?

```
LIST[IN_USE].ptr = start;
LIST[IN_USE].size = *start;
```

I can't understand the logic of this process.

Comment: If you know the purpose of the code please explain it. That will make analysising it much easier.

Comment: It's just a free function. I mean I know how this function works but I don't understand the logic, what did he write. How does this piece of code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
u8* start = e->ptr;
u8* user_ptr = start + HEADER;
```

in malloc function, the address that `user_ptr` point to `start + HEADER`, so in free function, we just restore the address of start to original address:

```
 u8* start = (u8*)ptr - HEADER;
```

```
LIST[IN_USE].ptr = &(*start);
```

Here, we reset `ptr` points to `start`. It's similar to

```
LIST[IN_USE].ptr = &(*start);
```

because, `*start` we deference the pointer to have the value that `start` pointer pointing to. Then, we use reference to have the address of this value, this is exactly the address of `start` pointer pointing to.
Here:

```
LIST[IN_USE].size = (u8) * ((u8*)ptr - HEADER);
```

`(u8*)ptr - HEADER` is `start`. So `* ((u8*)ptr - HEADER)` is `*start`. Then `u8 *(start)` is value that start points to with the type `u8`